# Running multiple sorts on JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS Array ...

```js
   var arr = [{
 "Event_code": "BW-087",
 "Interest_area": "Information technology",
 "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-161",
 "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
 "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-114",
 "Interest_area": "Nursing and midwifery",
 "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-033",
 "Interest_area": "",
 "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "General information session",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-115",
 "Interest_area": "Food, Nutrition and dietetics",
 "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-060",
 "Interest_area": "Sport",
 "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
 "End_time": "3:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": true
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-081",
 "Interest_area": "Information technology",
 "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
 "End_time": "9:30 AM",
 "Session_type": "Course information session",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-170",
 "Interest_area": "",
 "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
 "End_time": "10:30 AM",
 "Session_type": "General information session",
 "all_day_evt": false,
 "clash": "This clashes with another session"
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-032",
 "Interest_area": "",
 "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
 "End_time": "10:00 AM",
 "Session_type": "General information session",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-096",
 "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
 "Start_time": "10:00 AM",
 "End_time": "12:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-163",
 "Interest_area": "Business",
 "Start_time": "10:00 AM",
 "End_time": "2:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": false,
 "clash": "This clashes with another session"
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-048",
 "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
 "Start_time": "12:00 PM",
 "End_time": "12:30 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-128",
 "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
 "Start_time": "12:00 PM",
 "End_time": "12:30 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": false,
 "clash": "This clashes with another session"
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-018",
 "Interest_area": "Sciences",
 "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
 "End_time": "2:30 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": false,
 "clash": "This clashes with another session"
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-013",
 "Interest_area": "Sciences, Engineering, Information technology, Architecture and built environment, Environment",
 "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
 "End_time": "1:00 PM",
 "Session_type": "Course information session",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-039",
 "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
 "Start_time": "1:00 PM",
 "End_time": "1:30 PM",
 "Session_type": "Experience",
 "all_day_evt": false
}, {
 "Event_code": "BW-162",
 "Interest_area": "Education and teaching",
 "Start_time": "1:00 PM",
 "End_time": "1:30 PM",
 "Session_type": "Tour",
 "all_day_evt": false,
 "clash": "This clashes with another session"
}]

    arr.sort((x,y) => y.all_day_evt- x.all_day_evt || ((new Date('1970/01/01 ' + x.Start_time)) - (new Date('1970/01/01 ' + y.Start_time))));

    console.log(arr);
```

I am looking to do 3 operations on this array ...

1. Group this array by "all_day_evt" key.
2. Sort this array within the 'true' subgroup, and 'false' subgroup by 'Start_time'.
3. Sort if there is a "clash" on 'start_time' ... with the "clashed event" showing up 2nd.

I am not sure how to implement the 3rd condition, any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Sample output shown below - highlighting how the clash events should line up. It should show up so that the event with "clash" key comes 2nd, not first.

For example, events "BW-013" & "BW-018" are clashing at start_time of 12:30 PM. So, 'BW-013' comes first, and then 'BW-018' shows up. Same goes with events 'BW-039' and 'BW-162' as shown in example output below.

```
[{
        "Event_code": "BW-013",
        "Interest_area": "Sciences, Engineering, Information technology, Architecture and built environment, Environment",
        "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
        "End_time": "1:00 PM",
        "Session_type": "Course information session",
        "all_day_evt": false
    },
    {
        "Event_code": "BW-018",
        "Interest_area": "Sciences",
        "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
        "End_time": "2:30 PM",
        "Session_type": "Tour",
        "all_day_evt": false,
        "clash": "This clashes with another session"
    },
    {
        "Event_code": "BW-039",
        "Interest_area": "Media, Communication and creative arts",
        "Start_time": "1:00 PM",
        "End_time": "1:30 PM",
        "Session_type": "Experience",
        "all_day_evt": false
    }, {
        "Event_code": "BW-162",
        "Interest_area": "Education and teaching",
        "Start_time": "1:00 PM",
        "End_time": "1:30 PM",
        "Session_type": "Tour",
        "all_day_evt": false,
        "clash": "This clashes with another session"
    }
]
```

Comment: The third condition seems to be the least of the issues as the `sort()` logic you haven isn't actually doing anything. Can you give an example of the output you're expecting to achieve

Comment: If you only want to know how to do the third one why do you even mention the other 2?

Comment: @liam Because all 3 conditions needs to run together. Its an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860015/js-array-sort-within-subgroups).

Comment: I think is that Liams point is that you're saying that you need to do X, Y and Z, and are asking about Z without even attempting to do X and Y, which should be done first as they will have an effect on Z

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, I have updated the array, Run the executable to see Condition 1 and Condition 2 in action. Let me know if you have any more questions. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: Hey @liam Is it making any sense now ? Simply jumble the array and run the script, you will see Cond 1 and Cond 2 works. Any other questions ?

Comment: @Slyper Can you show the desired output at each individual stage of sort?

Comment: @Slyper - Your code sorts the object in the expected order only.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilAggarwal for taking a look. Please see event 'BW-018' & 'BW-013'. They are in wrong order.

Comment: @Slyper - both have `all_day_evt` `false`, same `Start_time` and clashed item coming 2nd. Is it not the desired result?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal 'BW-018' is coming first. It needs to come after 'BW-013'. 'BW-018' has a 'clash' message. It should come after 'BW-013'. Did you run my executable code ?

Comment: @Slyper - I have added an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following. You need to add additional condition of `clash`

```js
 var arr = [{"Event_code":"BW-087","Interest_area":"Information technology","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-161","Interest_area":"Media, Communication and creative arts","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-114","Interest_area":"Nursing and midwifery","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-033","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"General information session","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-115","Interest_area":"Food, Nutrition and dietetics","Start_time":"9:30 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-060","Interest_area":"Sport","Start_time":"9:30 AM","End_time":"3:00 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":true},{"Event_code":"BW-081","Interest_area":"Information technology","Start_time":"9:00 AM","End_time":"9:30 AM","Session_type":"Course information session","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-170","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:30 AM","End_time":"10:30 AM","Session_type":"General information session","all_day_evt":false,"clash":"This clashes with another session"},{"Event_code":"BW-032","Interest_area":"","Start_time":"9:30 AM","End_time":"10:00 AM","Session_type":"General information session","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-096","Interest_area":"Media, Communication and creative arts","Start_time":"10:00 AM","End_time":"12:00 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-163","Interest_area":"Business","Start_time":"10:00 AM","End_time":"2:00 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":false,"clash":"This clashes with another session"},{"Event_code":"BW-048","Interest_area":"Media, Communication and creative arts","Start_time":"12:00 PM","End_time":"12:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-128","Interest_area":"Media, Communication and creative arts","Start_time":"12:00 PM","End_time":"12:30 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":false,"clash":"This clashes with another session"},{"Event_code":"BW-018","Interest_area":"Sciences","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"2:30 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":false,"clash":"This clashes with another session"},{"Event_code":"BW-013","Interest_area":"Sciences, Engineering, Information technology, Architecture and built environment, Environment","Start_time":"12:30 PM","End_time":"1:00 PM","Session_type":"Course information session","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-039","Interest_area":"Media, Communication and creative arts","Start_time":"1:00 PM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Experience","all_day_evt":false},{"Event_code":"BW-162","Interest_area":"Education and teaching","Start_time":"1:00 PM","End_time":"1:30 PM","Session_type":"Tour","all_day_evt":false,"clash":"This clashes with another session"}];
arr.sort((x,y) => y.all_day_evt- x.all_day_evt || ((new Date('1970/01/01 ' + x.Start_time)) - (new Date('1970/01/01 ' + y.Start_time))) || Boolean(x.clash) - Boolean(y.clash));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Perfect @NikhilAggarwal, That's what I was looking for -- the Boolean condition. Can't believe these down-voters. They kept down-voting without even understating the problem. Anyway, I really appreciate all your help. Thanks so much.